# Services that require portmap

Tags: linux, security, centos

I am installing a CentOS 5.3 server in an environment with pre-established security policies.  One of the policies is that portmap should not be installed.  To be honest I am not sure if I really need it or not.

What other common services require portmap?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's only used by legacy(-ish) RPC services.

For CentOS, if you're not using NFS or NIS, then you can do without it.

Answer (score 0):

Even if you do use NFS, you may **still** disable portmap on the server with one caveat, your clients would need to connect with the `-o nolock` option instead, which is the behaviour of older NFS.